# Xamarin Forms Android service crashes right after the boot in mscorlib.dll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, background-process, mscorlib

I want to run my background service at the boot, I'm on Android using Xamarin Forms. I created the service following the great example “LongRunningTaskService” of Rob Gibbens https://github.com/RobGibbens/XamarinFormsBackgrounding
and works perfectly but I needed it at the boot and not triggered by the UI. I added the service at the boot and there's a crash right after the boot in mscorlib.dll. The crash happens even removing all code and not doing anything apart the broadcast listener.

here the broadcast listener

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
namespace FormsBackgrounding.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class StartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            //if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionBootCompleted)
            //{ 
                //Intent timerIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(LongRunningTaskService));
               //Application.Context.StartService(timerIntent);
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

here the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.arteksoftware.formsbackgrounding">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application android:label="FormsBackgrounding">
    <receiver android:name="StartReceiver">
         <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".LongRunningTaskService" ></service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

the crash from log

```
Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arteksoftware.formsbackgrounding/files/.__override__/mscorlib.dll'.
 637): The first listener is added
Image addref mscorlib[0xe1bfe280] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arteksoftware.formsbackgrounding/files/.__override__/mscorlib.dll[0xeaf8c800]: 2
Prepared to set up assembly 'mscorlib' (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arteksoftware.formsbackgrounding/files/.__override__/mscorlib.dll)
AOT module '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arteksoftware.formsbackgrounding/files/.__override__/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/
/lib/x86/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/df84ee74/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/
/lib/x86/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arteksoftware.formsbackgrounding/files/.__override__/mscorlib.dll'.
Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arteksoftware.formsbackgrounding/files/.__override__/mscorlib.dll.config'.
Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/df84ee74/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
mono_threads_platform_set_priority: unknown policy 3
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1462 (msbackgrounding)
debuggerd: handling request: pid=1445 uid=10068 gid=10068 tid=1462
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:7.0/NRD90M/genymo09131924:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 1445, tid: 1462, name: msbackgrounding  >>> com.arteksoftware.formsbackgrounding <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'mono_threads_platform_set_priority: unknown policy 3'
    eax 00000000  ebx 000005a5  ecx 000005b6  edx 00000006
    esi cd3ef978  edi cd3ef920
    xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
    eip ef775bb9  ebp cd3ef748  esp cd3ef6ec  flags 00000292

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000bb9  [vdso:ef775000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
    #01 pc 0007a2ec  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+28)
    #02 pc 00075b35  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+85)
    #03 pc 0002784a  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+42)
    #04 pc 0001ee26  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+86)
    #05 pc 00270657  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so
```

Anyone faced same issue? got any workaround?

Comment: Could you please try clean the project and run it on other device/emulator?

Comment: I've tried without success on two different devices ( genymotion api 21 and api 24) and also on xamarin android simulator. same result